# Good rich text editor to be used for custom blog

Tags: html, blogs, rich-text-editor

I am working on a project (website) where I need to make a feature where users are able to publish a post, like a blog, so I wanted to keep the post data in the database. What rich text editor can you recommend to me, that is not very hard to use and that will replace the HTML text area?

Also, if I just directly put the content from rich text editor into a database field, what format the content actually will be? I am thinking of HTML string but not sure. So if it's HTML I can just echo the whole thing when displaying the post content? Sorry for that much questions and thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com/) or [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: not sure why they deleted php tag when it was related to it too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think TinyMCE suits for your blog.

> TinyMCE is a platform independent web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG.
>   editor.

Take a look at the site: http://www.tinymce.com/ Also you can give a try here: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php

Comment: I think this is perfect for me, it can return whole content in html string which I can put into database. Also found this plugin for TinyMCE to additionally support image uploading: http://www.binpress.com/app/tinymce-image-uploader-manager/23

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/index.php)

It's pretty standard. I know it comes as an optional editor with Joomla! installation - so you know it's at least stable enough to be used in a large distribution of a widely-used CMS.